How to log all function calls from a program
Currently i'm trying to reverse engineer a game. I want to see which functions are called when a certain action in game is taken. i want to do this to establish context and to see which function i should take a look at. i already tried to find the desired function via cheat engine but it didn't work for my situation. So my next approach is to log all functions and see which are called when.
i found 2 techniques to implent that:
1.hook all functions and inside the hooked function call a print function
2.place a break point at every function and log the function when the breakpoint gets poped
problem with these 2 is that they both create large overhead and apparently too many breakpoints can cause the program to crash(atleast that's what was stated in this article https://gamehacking.academy/pages/7/06/)
my question now is, are there better ways to achive what i want? if so i would appreciate some resources.
